# How the electric field of those dipoles created in that directions? (configuration added)

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, dipole-moment

[image]

I am a little bit confused how the electric field produced by dipole $P_1$ at $\vec{r_2}=(\ell,0,0)$ is equal to $\boldsymbol{E}_{1}\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{2}\right)=-\frac{k p_{1}}{l^{3}} \hat{z}$

and the electric field produced by dipole $P_2$ at $\vec{r_1}=(0,0,0)$ is equal to :$\boldsymbol{E}_{2}\left(\boldsymbol{r}_{1}\right)=\frac{2 k p_{2}}{l^{3}} \hat{x}$

According to my understanding the electric field of dipoles are $\vec{E}= \frac{k p}{r^{3}}(2 \hat{r} \cos \theta+\hat{\theta} \sin \theta)$. I do not understand how it can yield from that formula. Am I supposed to work with spherical coordinates? and if yes I think that $P_2$ should have component in $\hat y$ as well.

Comment: Better formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_from_an_electric_dipole Your formula is for when the dipole moment points in the positive $z$ direction.

Comment: I am a little bit confuse when do I use your formula and when do I use the formula I mentioned, what is the difference between them?

Comment: If you use your formula, you have to interpret the $\theta$ in it as the angle from the direction of $\vec p$, not as the angle from the $+z$-axis.